# Could not save objects into a many many to relation in datanucles JDO

Tags: database, jdo, datanucleus

I'm having a question with saving objects to many to many relationship. Following are the two classes.

Entity 1 => Application

Entity 2 => User

Application can have many *Users* and User can have many *Applications*.

Since actual class having lot of fields I will only put required part of the mapping.

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Application implements Serializable {
    -----
    @Persistent(table="APPLICATIONUSER")
    @Join(column="APPID")
    @Element(column="USERID")
    private Set<User> users;
}

@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class User implements Serializable {
   ----
   @Persistent(mappedBy="users")
   private Set<Application> applications;
}
```

I have refer the URL "http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/orm/many_to_many.html" to find this mapping information.

Now I want to add new User to the Application. Following are the two scenarios which I have tried. Please note that all transactions are happening on same Persistence Manager object.

**Case 1**

1. retrieving an existing user.
2. Adding that User to the Application

Result => Successful

**Case 2**

1. Creating a new User Object
2. Setting the user id
3. Adding that User to the Application

Result => **Not working** (It not throwing any errors. Just data not getting inserted). I wonder why I could not just add a new User object to the Application and save it.

If any one knows, please show me the problem of this..  Thank you..

Comment: and the log says ? If you're debugging a problem that is the first place you (should) look ...

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding about log. I have really forgot about that. I will check it.

Comment: I found the issue. It was I have not set a required field on that object. But when I running the JUnit test case, there were no errors and test case getting passed. But as you suggested I have enable the log4j and then I saw the issue. Thank you very much for the hint...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. Actually the source code is in a jar file and I'm using JUnit to test each method. As I mentioned in the question, there were no errors showing and test case is getting passed.

But as the "DataNucleus" suggest, I have enabled the log4j and then I was able to find out the problem. It is because I have not set a required field on User class.

Anyway I wonder why test case is not showing this error. Maybe a configuration issue.